# how do you know if a collection of subsets is a field?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, field-theory

Let $\Omega=${0,1,2,3,...}

Let B be the collection of subsets of $\Omega$ such that C $\in$ B if and only if either C or $C^{c}$ is a finite set.

Is B a field? Is it a $\sigma$-field?

Here is my thought process and I would appreciate if the community could offer advice.

According to pg. 19 of [this book](http://www.drchristiansalas.org.uk/MathsandPhysics/Measure/BillingsleyProbabilityandMeasure.pdf) the following are 3 properties of a field:

1. $\Omega \in B$
2. $C \in B --> C^{c} \in B$
3. $C,D \in B$ --> $C\cup D \in B$

A $\sigma$-field the same 2 properties above except the 3rd property is strengthened to only countable unions and needs to contain singletons.

Let C=$\varnothing$.  Then $C^{c}=\Omega$. C is finite and $C^{c}$ is infinite.  Therefore $C \in $B.

But if I let $C=\{1,3,5,...\}$ then $C^{c} = \{2,4,6,...\}$.  In this case both are infinite, and therefore $C$ does not exist in $B$.  So this violates property #2 above. Right? That means $B$ is not a field, nor is it a $\sigma$-field.

Comment: I guess you're right.  If C and its compliment are not in B then no problem.  I think the "if and only if" part of this problem is throwing me off.  With C and its compliment being infinite I feel like I found a case where C is not in B. But from what you are saying it does not violate rule #2.  So it seems like you are implying B is a field.

Comment: I edited my question to define the $\sigma$-field. But I'm confused about why you think B is not a $\sigma$-field.  I think it is not a $\sigma$-field because there are no singletons like 0.5.  Right?

Comment: My understanding is a singleton can be constructed using a finite intersection of intervals. But I'm not sure I can do so in B

Comment: I think you are using my original argument to show that B is not a $\sigma$ -field.  What you are saying is exactly what I said above.  Let C = {1,3,5,..} odd numbers.  Then the compliment is the set of even numbers {0,2,4,...}.  Both are infinite and thus C is not in B by definition of B. And since we found one example of a C that is not in B that is a missing singleton, this must mean B can't be a $\sigma$-field. Right?

Comment: If B is a $\sigma$-field why does O need to be in B? Is O a singleton?

Comment: So if B is a regular field (which we think it is) then O is in B?

Comment: So O not being in B is not a problem for B being a regular field.  What if I removed the "if and only if" restriction.  Does this change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, all finite subsets of $\Omega$ are in $B$.

Property 1 : $\Omega^C = \emptyset \in B$, so by definition $\Omega \in B$ since $\emptyset$ is finite.

Property 2 : Note that $C = C^{C^{C}} $, so if $C \in B$ is finite then by defintion $C^C \in B$.  On the other hand, if $C \in B$ is infinite, then by defintion $C^C$ must be finite for otherwise $C \notin B$. So $C^C \in B$.

(A shorter proof of property 3 is provided in the EDIT at the bottom of this answer.)

Property 3 : If $C,D \in B$ then, if $C \cup D$ is finite, then $C \cup D \in B$ so by property 2 $(C \cup D)^C \in B$.

If $C \cup D$ is infinite and $(C \cup D)^C$ is finite, then by defintion $(C \cup D)^C \in B$.

This leaves the case where both $(C \cup D)$ and $(C \cup D)^C$ are infinite.  Here we note De Morgan's Law $(C \cup D)^C = C^C \cap D^C$.  Note that both $C^C$ and $D^C$ are in $B$ by property 2. If both $C^C$ and $D^C$ are finite, then so is their intersection and the result follows.  If both $C^C$ and $D^C$ are infinite, then since $C,D \in B$ we know that both $C$ and $D$ must be finite and so must their union, and again the result follows.  This just leaves the case where one of $C$, $D$ is finite and the other is infinite. Without loss of generality, let $C$ be infinite and $D$ be finite. In this case, if $C \in B$ then $C^C$ must be finite, so $C^C \cap D^C$ must also be finite and therefore in $B$.

This shows $B$ satisfies all three field properties listed. (A rather case-bound demonstration.)

To see that $B$ is a $\sigma$-field according to your definition, note that all singletons are in $B$ since, by definition, $B$ contains all finite sets.  Closure under countable union follows immediately by induction.

**EDIT (Sep 14):**  Here is a shorter and slightly more attractive proof of property 3.

If $(C \cup D) = (C \cup D)^{C^C}$ is finite, then $(C \cup D)^C \in B$ since its complement is finite.

If $(C \cup D) = (C \cup D)^{C^C}$ is infinite, then if $(C \cup D) \in B$ then it must be because its complement is finite. So $(C \cup D)^C \in B$.

Comment: So it seems like you broke up the 3rd property of the field into 4 quadrants.  Top left C and D finite. Top right C finite and D infinite.  Bottom left C infinite D finite.  Bottom right C infinite and D infinite. Inside each quadrant you unioned C and D and determined whether the result is finite or not and determined whether each quadrant exists in B. Because each quadrant is in B you concluded overall property 3 holds for all cases, and B is therefore a field. Is this correct?

Comment: In order to determine whether each quadrant is in B you took the compliment of the result inside each quadrant and used property 2 to determine if its in B.

Comment: @user1068636 Yes, it is a very case-bound argument, so it is a bit confusing and takes a bit of patience.  Property 3 relies largely on property 2, De Morgan's Law, and that the union of finite sets is finite and that the intersection of two sets is finite if one of them is.

Comment: @user1068636 I have inserted a much shorter proof of property 3 as an edit at the bottom of my previous answer.